# Android lolipop. Не отображаются нотификации при закрытом приложении

Tags: java, android, android-notification

Столкнулся с проблемой отображения нотификаций в android lolipop. При открытом приложении они в статус бар уходят, но если приложение закрыть и удалить из "Недавние запущенные", то отображаться перестают. На 4-х версиях андроида все работает исправно, нотификации отображаются и при оффнутом приложении, и после перезапуска девайса. Вот метод для отображения

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void sendNotification(String body, String title, String badge) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("from_notify", true);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, Integer.valueOf(badge), intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setShowWhen(true)
                .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

[Receiver](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5ad672abfb34690fe075fe304ae1019c)

[Manifest](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a9f057dd0da3f4b68b37f988b0c5226d)

Comment: BroadcastReceiver  используете? Покажите код манифеста для ресивера. Ну и код Activity, где регистрируете ресивер.

Comment: @Suvitruf да, Reciever идет от GCM. Прикрутил код

Comment: Добавлю наблюдений: на сам девайс пуши приходят, в логе google services (`*#*#426#*#*`) `1: Received com.<app bundle> CANCELED time=4`

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, а метод `sendNotification` вызывается? Проблема именно в неотображении уведомления вообще?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Логи говорят что всё вызывается но именно нотификации визуально не приходят..

Comment: Попробуйте id не равно нулю задать для notify... С нулем, afair, были какие-то косяки (в примерах из документации google везде пишет 1, например)

Comment: @YuraIvanov К сожалению не помогло=(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В последних версиях FCM (Firebase Cloud Messages) корпорация добра изменила порядок обработки уведомлений. Теперь оно (Андроид) само решает, как обработать пуш. Если приложение в бэкграунде, то пуш покажется с настройками по умолчанию.

Цитата:

> When your app is in the background, Android directs notification
>   messages to the system tray. A user tap on the notification opens the
>   app launcher by default.

Что значит:

> Когда ваше приложение в бэкграунде, Андроид сам покажет уведомление,
>   при клике на который откроется ваше Апп.

Подробности тут https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive. Это происходит для всех сообщений с типом **Notification message**

Пример:

```
{
    "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "great match!",
      "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "icon" : "myicon"
    }
  }
```

Чтобы избежать этого, для самостоятельной обработки пушей используйте тип Data, как указано здесь https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
Пример

```
{
   "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
   "data" : {
     "Nick" : "Mario",
     "body" : "great match!",
     "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
   },
 }
```

Соответственно, такая же проблема есть и наоборот - если все уведомления имеют тип Data, то они просто перестают показываться, потому что система ждёт Notification message.